# Automatic construction of a colormap around the value zero

Tags: matlab, plot, color-mapping

I often want to plot a difference image that ranges from some negative number to some positive one.  The issue with that is that matlab's colormaps scale only from the min value to the max value but do not care about some middle value (this case zero). For example, I have produced the `peaks` image with a single pixel different:

[image]

where the original  looks like this:

[image]

So zero values are blue at the  top image and green at the bottom... (using jet colormap as an example)

I'd like to built a colormap that will automatically represent zero values as the same color no matter what will be the min\max values.  How can I do that?

Comment: I think you can achieve that by scaling everything to a fixed interval prior to plotting, such as `[-1,1]`.

Comment: use the colormapeditor: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/colormapeditor.html there is explained how to focus green at zero

Comment: Robocob specifically asked for an automatic implementation so he wouldn't need to open the colormap editor each time...

Comment: you could use `caxis` to control the color mapping by using a zero-centered range, that way `0` is always in the middle (assuming you are using scaled color mapping as opposed to direct mapping)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [this tool](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36212-matlab-blue-white-red-colorbar-while-zero-always-corresponds-to-white-color)  from the FEX. It generates  blue-white-red colormap, with zero always corresponds to white color. For the case you want to include more than two colors, dig into the [code](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36212-matlab-blue-white-red-colorbar-while-zero-always-corresponds-to-white-color/content/b2r.m) and adapt it to your needs.

There are a few more options in the FEX that do similar things (here's [one](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/39453-adaptive-colormap-function-creates-a-colormap-specific-to-data), and [another one](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/39985-zerocolor))...
[image]

Answer (score 9):

The color mapping can be controlled using the `caxis` function (which sets the `CLim` property of the current axes object). The assumption of course is that a scaled color mapping is in use, as opposed to direct color mapping (read the `CDataMapping` property). By using a zero-centered range as input, you can ensure that zero is always in the middle.

Here is an example:

```
load penny
P = 4*(P./255) - 1;        %# not centered around zero
imagesc(P), axis image off
colormap(lbmap(64,'BrownBlue')), colorbar
```

[image: skewed_range]

Now we adjust the color mapping to make it symmetric around zero:

```
c = max(abs([min(P(:)),max(P(:))]));
caxis([-c c])
```

[image: symmetric_range]

Note that I am using the [Light Bartlein color scheme](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/17555-light-bartlein-color-maps) which was designed as a divergent palette to highlight differences between two extremes.

If the original range is very skewed, you might want to resample the colormap to give it more values in the sub-range that is over-stretched.

Comment: thanks Amro, but if I understand correctly using this assumes that I need to center my colormap around zero, where most of the times the lower and upper limits are not symmetric around zero. So the way to deal with it is to set the limits on whichever is absolute value is greater I guess.

Comment: Yes I assumed that was applicable for you... After all there are lots of applications where the zero-value is of significance (for example showing topographic maps with the sea level represented at zero). The easiest way was to use a zero-centered color range, with an appropriate symmetric colormap and let MATLAB do the scaling. The other approach is to build it piecewise, with each piece being a linear mapping between two endpoints, that way you could have as many "nodes" as you wish (similar to the `colormapeditor` mentioned above)

Comment: `c = max(abs((P(:)));` is enough

Answer (score 3):

I like the other answers, especially the one by @Amro. But it looks so complicated :) And your `caxis` parameters don't need to depend on your input, you can simply grab them from the axis. All this can be a one-liner:

```
a = gca; % or whatever you use to access your axis handle
a.CLim = max(abs(a.CLim)) * [-1 1];
```

That's it. This works in MATLAB R2014b onwards, which has the new figure handle system (see more details [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics_transition/graphics-handles-are-now-objects-not-doubles.html)). In earlier versions (and new ones, if you prefer), you would use

```
a = gca; % or whatever you use to access your axis handle
set(a, 'CLim', max(abs(get(a, 'CLim'))) * [-1 1]);
```

or, using `caxis`,

```
a = gca; % or whatever you use to access your axis handle
caxis(a, max(abs(caxis(a))) * [-1 1]);
```

Automating this is fairly easy as well:

```
a = gca; % or whatever you use to access your axis handle
addlistener(a, 'CLimMode', 'PostSet', @(h, e) caxis(e.AffectedObject, max(abs(caxis(e.AffectedObject))) * [-1 1]));
```

This allows you to do this

```
for ii = -5 : 5
    imagesc([-1 0 10^ii]);
    pause(0.2);
end
```

and the middle stripe (representing 0) is always the middle color of the colorbar.

Comment: Thanks for `addlistener`. Didn't know this existed, but it seems very useful.