# MATLAB imagesc: Use black as mid-color for value 0

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, zero, colormap

I want to use *imagesc* to plot a quantity where all of positive, negative, and close-to-zero values are important. I want the close-to-zeros to be black, but there is no default *colormap* that provides such a feature.

For example, using *colormap(hot)* assigns black to the lowest (in this case: negative) number, which looks bad:

`figure, imagesc(Xvalues, Yvalues, Quantity)
colorbar, colormap(hot), axis equal, axis off`
[image]

Observe that 0 is assigned some unflashy red, which makes the regions of vanishing value hard to see.

Is there any way to use (e.g.) *colormap(hot)* for the positive values and some blue-ish *colormap* for the negative values, with both meeting at a black zero?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16781255/automatic-construction-of-a-colormap-around-the-value-zero

Comment: @AnderBiguri Wow, how did I miss that with my beforehand searches. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I see that a link to a similar question is posted as a comment to the question here. The answer provided there is much better than mine.

You can make a custom colormap. Colormaps have three columns and any number of rows. Each column represents one color (Red,Green,Blue, respectively). For example, if you want a color map from red to blue you could make one with:

```
mymap = [zeros(256,2),linspace(1,0,256)';linspace(0,1,256)', zeros(256,2)]
```

and then use it with

```
colormap(mymap)
```

I don't know of an easy way to make black equal zero although one must exist. The best advise I can give you to make that work is to calculate how many rows each color needs based on your minimum and maximum values.

Comment: That's a cool approach too. In the meanwhile I solved my problem by slightly customizing the lbmap-script linked in the other thread, and your answer helped me understanding how that script works. Thank you.