# Center a colormap around 0 in Mayavi

Tags: python, mayavi, color-mapping

I'm plotting a point cloud and coloring by residual error. I'd like the colormap to remain centered on 0, so that 0 error is white.

I see [answers for matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16781255/automatic-construction-of-a-colormap-around-the-value-zero). What about Mayavi?

```
from mayavi import mlab
mlab.points3d(x, y, z, e, colormap='RdBu')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set the `vmin` and `vmax` of the colormap explicitly with `mlab.points3d`. So, you could just make sure that `vmin` = `-vmax`. Something like this:

```
mylimit = 10
mlab.points3d(x, y, z, e, colormap='RdBu',vmin=-mylimit,vmax=mylimit)
```

Or, you could set the limit automatically with something like:

```
mylimit = max(abs(e.min()),abs(e.max()))
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anybody wishes to do this but so that the full extent of the colorbar is used, here is a solution I made (with help from [here](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/example_custom_colormap.html)) for mayavi that stretches the colorbar so that the centre of it is on zero:

```
#Mayavi surface
s = mlab.surf(data)
#Get the lut table of the data
lut = s.module_manager.scalar_lut_manager.lut.table.asarray()

maxd = np.max(data)
mind = np.min(data)
#Data range
dran = maxd - mind

#Proportion of the data range at which the centred value lies
zdp = abs(mind / dran)    

#The +0.5's here are because floats are rounded down when converted to ints
#index equal portion of distance along colormap
cmzi = int(zdp * 255 + 0.5)
#linspace from zero to 128, with number of points matching portion to side of zero
topi = np.linspace(0, 127, cmzi) + 0.5
#and for other side
boti = np.linspace(128, 255, 255 - cmzi) + 0.5    

#convert these linspaces to ints and map the new lut from these    
shift_index = np.hstack([topi.astype(int), boti.astype(int)])
s.module_manager.scalar_lut_manager.lut.table = self.lut[shift_index]

#Force update of the figure now that we have changed the LUT
mlab.draw()
```

Note that if you wish to do this multiple times for the same surface (ie. if you're modifying the mayavi scalars rather than redrawing the plot) you need to make a record of the initial lut table and modify that each time.